# Android 3.x emulators only support the WXGA skin

Tags: android, android-emulator

For some reason, the Android 3.x emulators only support the WXGA skin. Why is that, and what can I do if I want to define an emulator for some other skin, just like all the other versions support? Do I have to use the resolution option, or can I somehow install the missing skins?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that

Because Android 3.x only shipped on tablets, most (if not all) running a WXGA resolution. Hence, there is little value in running an Android 3.x emulator at any other resolution.

> Do I have to use the resolution option

Yes.